# Angular data binding multiple classes

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I have a controller with a variable 'LoadPercentage' that returns an integer 0-100 which then animates a progress bar. I was expecting this to give me a single class with the load progress: `progress-75` or the likes.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-{{controller.LoadPercentage}}">
    <div class="completed-bar"></div>
</div>
```

However, it produces varying results such as:

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-20 progress-100">
    <div class="completed-bar"></div>
</div>
```

There are multiple classes added which obviously causes the progress bar to become stuck at the point of the first class added. In this example that's 20%.

First off - what causes the second class to be bound? I'm guessing there is some angular behaviour causing this but I cannot find anything relating to it online.

Secondly, is there a way to achieve this? I cannot see a way to do it with ng-class and can't find any examples of adding numeric classes where the number of possible classes is larger than you would want to add into an ng-class condition.

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is use ng-class with your own expression that determines the value needed and returns the appropriate class.

Also, never bind directly to a primitive (string, number, bool) directly on your scope.  Always reference things using dot notation: eg  instead of just value stored directly on scope.

Doing otherwise can cause bindings errors leading to issues like you see with multiple classes.

See documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: Adding `ng-class: 'progress-' + controller.LoadPercentage` to my class attribute still binds multiple classes though. It makes sense as there is nothing telling it to remove the old classes... As mentioned above I don't want to add a hundred clauses to my ngClass!

Comment: I'm saying instead of evaluating an expression directly there you can instead provide a function that is on your scope that returns the expected value. Also, you need to not have primitive values bound directly to your scope.  Move load percentage inside of an object.  Even scope.values.loadpercentage would be fine.